# Invoking the focus method causes onblur to fire endlessly

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml, onblur, onfocus

I want to validate an input box when the user moves on to another field. I have the following code which works fine.

```js
validate = (v) => {
  if (v.value=="yes") return;
  alert("Value must be exactly 'yes'. Please rectify.");
  //v.focus();
}
```

```html
<p>Enter only 'yes' in this field:</p>
<input onblur='validate(this);' />
```

However, if I add invoking the `focus` method with the intention to highlight to the user to fix the error before continuing, the `onblur` method is fired endlessly. Why is this so?

The fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/OldGeezer/8xfLwvn6/4/

On further testing, I find that the endless `onblur` does not happen if it loses focus because I click on another application window. It happens if I simply click another part of the web page (in Chrome).

Comment: you lose focus when `alert()` end, you can simply verify this use your current code in question.

Comment: btw, this is really annoying, please use other method (like form validation) to do this. (User: let me move on, I would fix this later!)

Comment: I'm not sure the spec for `alert()`, though. so I'd not post as answer.

Comment: This is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using `alert()` removes focus from the active element which causes `blur` to trigger. Thereby, according to your script , `blur` triggers continuously. Use `console.log()` which helps you to understand about this much better.

Comment: `console.log` would not trigger `blur` so may not help to understand something.

Comment: In order to check whether `blur` fires continuously,  log the results in console. You will get to know about this theteafter.

Comment: All of these answers are focusing (no pun intended) on the wrong thing. It's not `alert` that's causing it to tirgger `blur`.  It's calling `focus` after the alert.  If you take the `focus` call out, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to w3schools:

> **Note:** The alert box takes the focus away from the current window, and forces the browser to read the message. Do not overuse this method, as it prevents the user from accessing other parts of the page until the box is closed.

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Alert takes focus away from the input creating an endless loop. The solution is to display the message in a different way. For example in a span element:

```
<p>Enter only 'yes' in this field:</p>
<input onblur="validate(this);" />  
<span id="message"></span>

<script>

validate = (v) => {
  if (v.value=="yes") return;
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Value must be exactly 'yes'. Please rectify.";
  v.focus();
}

</script>
```

Comment: But my `alert` is *before* calling the `focus` method.

Comment: @Old Geezer. The order doesn't matter, because javascript is mono-thread and the events are processed all after your code. https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4

Comment: @ClaudiaChersin I added a `console.log` line after the `alert` and there was no console output until the `alert` dialog is closed.

Comment: @Old Geezer Yes, of course the console.log occours after the alert is closed (alert is sync). Is the onblur that is executed only after the execution of validate function is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is constantly run onblur function, you run it again and again and on each iteration it gives you alert.

1. Input gets onblur event, shows alert, automatically focuses on input.
2. You click anywhere and onblur fires again, shows alert, and focuses on input again.

And you do it in a loop so to say.

Instead of focusing on input, you can just give it border color. This way your onblur will fire once only.